# c# how to convert xml to dictionary to get values of one attribute and multiple elments

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary

I need to convert xml to dictionary. I've never done that before. Can you please show me a code example how to convert this xml to dictionary to get values like this:

```
Key: Vendor and Value: BankRed
Key: CustRef and Value: dfas16549464
Key: InvP and Value: 1, 12
```

Here is xml:

```
<root>
    <Vendor name = "BankRed">
       <CustRef>dfas16549464</CustRef>
       <InvP> 1, 12</InvP>
    </Vendor>
</root>
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what will be your dictionary key and what will be your dictionary values?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo KEY - Vendor VALUE - bankRed....KEY - CustRef VALUE - dfas16549464.... KEY InP VALUE - 1,12

Comment: Wouldn't a custom type be better than a dictionary here?

Comment: Actually, why is the Key not `BankRed` for all of them? Surely this makes sense as `CustRef` and `InvP` are descendant nodes of the `Vendor = "BankRed` node. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do with clarifying a bit but this achieves the desired effect assuming that the Vendor attribute name should be the Key for the Vendor section, though you haven't been clear

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("path to your xml file");

var dict = xml.Descendants("Vendors")
              .Elements()
              .ToDictionary(r => r.Attribute("name").Value, r => r.Value);
```

Assuming an XML structure:

```
<root>
   <Vendors>
       <Vendor name="BankRed">
           <CustRef>dfas16549464</CustRef>
           <InvP> 1, 12</InvP>
       </Vendor>
   </Vendors>
   <Vendors>
       <Vendor name="BankBlue">
           <CustRef>foo</CustRef>
           <InvP>bar</InvP>
       </Vendor>
   </Vendors>
</root>
```

You will get a `Dictionary<string, string>` with two elements that looks like: -

- **Key**: BankRed
- **Values**: dfas16549464 1, 12
- **Key**: BankBlue
- **Values**: foo bar

However, I think you're taking the wrong approach. A better idea would be to create a custom type `Vendor` to store this information, for example:

```
public class Vendor
{
    public Vendor()
    { }

    public string CustRef { get; set; }
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public string InvP { get; set; }
}
```

And the query would become:

```
var query = (from n in xml.Descendants("Vendors")
          select new Vendor()
          {
               VendorName = n.Element("Vendor").Attribute("name").Value,
               CustRef = n.Descendants("Vendor").Select(x => x.Element("CustRef").Value).SingleOrDefault(),
               InvP = n.Descendants("Vendor").Select(x => x.Element("InvP").Value).SingleOrDefault()
          }).ToList();
```

Which will give you a list of `Vendor`s that look like this:

[image]

The data is now much easier to work with.

Comment: +1, but there are APIs out there that can serialize and deserialize Xml to POCOs automatically - and if the OP searched briefly, he'd find them :)

Answer (score 0):

i've writen a code and tested it. i hope that's what you need, though your questiong isn't clear on why you need it:
the class Entity for the use of the dictionary:

public class Entity
   {
      private string CustRef;
      private string InvP;

```
  public Entity(string custRef, string invP)
  {
     CustRef = custRef;
     InvP = invP;
  }
}
```

and the convert code:

```
     Dictionary<string, Entity> myTbl = new Dictionary<string, Entity>();
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(@"d:\meXml.xml");
     XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;
     foreach (XmlNode childNode in root.ChildNodes)
     {
        myTbl[childNode.Attributes[0].Value] = new Entity(
           childNode.FirstChild.InnerText, 
           childNode.LastChild.InnerText);
     }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using below code:

```
Dictionary<int, string> elements = xml.Elements(ns + "root")
        .Select(sp => new { 
                              CustRef = (string)(sp.Attribute("CustRef")), 
                              vendor = (string)(sp.Attribute("Vendor")) 
                          })
        .ToDictionary(sp => sp.CustRef, sp => sp.Vendor);
```

Comment: `CustRef` is a string, not an int.

Comment: The dictionary still has an `int` as its `Key` type